# Best way to query DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm trying to write a GraphQL server that queries an AWS DynamoDB store.

For the purpose of this question, the GraphQL part is irrelevant except for the fact that the arguments come in the form:

```
{
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2,
   key3: value3
}
```

These key/value pairs are used to query against the database. Strict equality only, nothing fancy. All arguments are optional.

Here's what I came up with:

```
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';

function constructParams(tableName, fields = {}) {
  const keys = Object.keys(fields);

  if (keys.length === 0) {
    return {
      TableName: tableName,
    };
  }

  const filters = keys.map(key => `#${key} = :${key}`);
  const attributeNames = keys.reduce((memo, key) => Object.assign(memo, {
    [`#${key}`]: key,
  }), {});
  const attributeValues = keys.reduce((memo, key) => Object.assign(memo, {
    [`:${key}`]: fields[key],
  }), {});

  return {
    TableName: tableName,
    FilterExpression: filters.join(' AND '),
    ExpressionAttributeNames: attributeNames,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: attributeValues,
  };
}

function query(tableName, fields = {}) {
  const docClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'ap-southeast-2' });
  const params = constructParams(tableName, fields);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data.Items);
      }
    });
  });
}

export default query;
```

This works fine. But goodness it's cumbersome. My `constructParams` function feels like so much unnecessary boilerplate. Such a function would be completely unnecessary with MongoDB.

Put it this way, why does it feel like I'm writing SQL for a NoSQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, what I'm trying to achieve just isn't possible with DynamoDB.

The `scan` method superficially offers this functionality. But it really just returns the entire table set and then filters afterward. Once your data set reaches a certain size, `scan` ceases to work.

The `query` method is what you really should be using. But it won't permit queries on more than two keys. This is simply appalling. It is profoundly inadequate for a so called database.

In other words, the DynamoDB API isn't just syntactically primitive. It's also functionally primitive.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is indeed the shortest code possible for what you are trying to achieve, because that's how DynamoDB expects filtering information for a `Scan`.

You can also consider moving filtering from DynamoDB-side to client-side, if it helps decrease code complexity. This won't change the consumed read capacity units, so your read cost will remain the same.